# J Language for learning math - "Math for the Layman"

Tags: math

Working programmer looking for a math refresher or just developing mathematical thinking. Saw J Language http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Books

The book "Math for the Layman" claims that the J language makes math easier to learn by providing interactive tools and simpler notation than conventional math. Can someone confirm this from experience, specifically for learning mathematical thinking? I thought I'd try a programming approach and maybe pick up a new language along the way. If not, I have my text books ready.

Is this worth my time?

Thank you.

Comment: I tend to disagree "J language makes math easier to learn" after seeing those J solutions to various code golfs :p

Answer (score 1):

Learning can never be a waste of time.  I'd say go for it, without knowing anything about J.

The math that I learned was acquired without the benefit of computers.  I have no experience with J, so I can't comment on that.

I personally don't think that a computer language will make you a mathematician.  If you've never taken calculus I don't see how a language or different notation will necessarily make it better or worse.  It needs to have complementary sources to really learn it well.

It may help since you're literate with computers, but the math will still take as long as it takes.  It's one thing to program a Bessel function; it's another to understand the differential equation it comes from, the problems it solves, orthogonality and relationships to other functions, etc.

Linear algebra is one area that greatly benefits from computer analysis.  The rules aren't too difficult, and computers save on the repetitive grunt work.

Another important bit is motivation.  I found that studying something for the sake of solving a particular problem was always important, especially with math.  Knowing how it would help me understand a problem in physics or engineering was a great motivator.  What will your motivation be?